# Error while using Raster Calculator to calculate NDVI in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, ndvi, sentinel-2

I exported 2 raster bands of Sentinel II (band 4 and band 8) to calculate NDVI **(B8-B4)/(B8+B4)**, these 2 rasters are in EPSG:32630 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N.  I'm currently using QGIS 3.26.1.

When I try to use raster calculator to do this NDVI my resluts are really bad, here are parameters I putted in : [image]

I'm supposed to have something that looks like what you can see on the left picture but I have what is on the right.

__________________desired result _____________________________________ result obtained
[image]

Comment: Which version of QGIS do you use?

Comment: please [edit] your question to explain exactly what you think is wrong with your output

Comment: Used Bands seems good, Raster calculator runs so there is no error?

Comment: I'm sorry I reversed the results in the text, I just edited it. @Matt

Comment: The results seem to be wrong because I have in result this kind of mixture between the 2 bands that you can see on the right image. I am trying to get something that looks like the one on the left. @MarcM

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works, I don't know if that's the main reason why my operation didn't work.

When I wrote the question the layers obtained by exporting the Sentinel II data were in "jp2" format, I noticed that when I re-saved them in GeoTIFF and used the raster calculator, I didn't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently have the same problem ... Formula for NDVI in raster calculator generates two 'twin images' as shown (QGis version 3.32.1-Lima, on Windows). Doing the exact same process in Saga-Gis as well as in 'SAGA Next Gen' (within Qgis toolbox) results in a correct one.